# Remove and install again

Tags: 22.04, uninstall, delete, reinstall

I believe I didn't install ubuntu 22.04 properly on my new asus.
Now I keep trying to install it again but I can't reach to the boot menu.
How can I completely remove it and then install?

Comment: You don't have to remove it. Just boot a live USB and reinstall. Ensure to boot the live USB in UEFI (not legacy BIOS) mode

Answer (score -1):

If you're having trouble accessing the boot menu to reinstall Ubuntu, you can follow these steps:

**1. Shutdown Your Computer:** Ensure that your computer is powered off.

**2. Access the BIOS/UEFI:** Turn on your computer and press the BIOS/UEFI access key immediately. This key is often displayed on the screen during the initial boot process. Common keys are Esc, Del, F2, F10, F12, or a combination of keys. Check your computer's manual or the manufacturer's website for the correct key.
(usually for asus device f2 is the key)

**3. Access the Boot Menu:** Once you're in the BIOS/UEFI, navigate to the boot menu. The key for accessing the boot menu often differs from the key for entering the BIOS. Look for an option like "Boot Menu" or "Boot Device Selection."

**4. Select Boot Device:** From the boot menu, select the device from which you want to boot. This could be a USB drive containing the Ubuntu installer.

**5. Install Ubuntu:** Boot from the Ubuntu installer and proceed with the installation. You'll be prompted to select the installation type during the installation process. Choose the option to erase the disk and install Ubuntu. This will remove the existing Ubuntu installation.

**6. Complete Installation:** Follow the on-screen instructions to complete the Ubuntu installation.

**7. Restart:** After the installation is complete, restart your computer. Make sure to remove the installation media (USB drive) so that your system boots from the internal drive.

These steps should help you reinstall Ubuntu from scratch. If you encounter any issues, please provide more details about the problems you're facing, and I'll do my best to assist you.

Here is a sample image of BIOS menu in my ASUS TUF A15 2020 Ryzen 9 laptop:

[image: Bios Image]

Here, you can see Ubuntu and Windows, so just switch it up as your boot device(live boot disk) from grub or anything else.